# Ransack opposite predicate :present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Ransack has abilities finding `User` that has a `first_name`:

```
User.search(:first_name_present => "1")
```

and the opposite, finding `User` with no `first_name` or blank:

```
User.search(:first_name_blank => "1")
```

.

Unfortunately,

`User.search(:first_name_present => "0")` **not equal with**

`User.search(:first_name_blank => "1")`

.

Is there anyway to make

`User.search(:first_name_present => "0")` **equal**

`User.search(:first_name_blank => "1")`,

or

`User.search(:first_name_present => "1")` **equal**

`User.search(:first_name_blank => "0")`?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could of course do something like this before calling `search`:

```
params[:q][:first_name_present] = "1" if
  params[:q][:first_name_blank].nil? ||
  params[:q][:first_name_blank] == "0"
```

I think it's good that these are not the same thing, otherwise, you couldn't have a checkbox to only find those users with empty first name – it would not allow a state listing all users. As it is now, unchecked checkboxes do not cause filtering.

Comment: Yeah. That's exactly what I've done already. I just curious, is there any direct predicate for blank/present opposition? Thx btw.